# View.onTouchEvent only registers ACTION_DOWN event

Tags: android, android-custom-view, touch-event, android-event

I'm implementing a custom `TextView` and I want to do some action when the view is touched. I figured the `onTouchEvent` method would give me the full range of touches on the view without having to use `setOnTouchListener` (I'm trying to do all my work inside the view instead of in the activity so it's portable), but the only touch event registered is `ACTION_DOWN`. If I set an `OnTouchListener` in the activity using this, I get the full range of touch events, but `onTouchEvent` doesn't.

Anyone know why this is the case, or can anyone offer me a solution that doesn't involve using `setOnTouchListener` (Which would prevent the implementing activity from setting its own listener)?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to return true to get the following events after a down.

Comment: If I do that, then any touch/click listeners applied from the activity never get triggered. I don't want to disable functionality. I just want to intercept any touches before they are dispatched, but still dispatch them. Calling `dispatchTouchEvent` just calls `onTouchEvent` again, causing a stack overflow (lol).

Comment: If you are in a ViewGroup container, you can override onInterceptTouchEvent() to monitor touch events being dispatched to your children.  Besides that (or directly hooking in to dispatchTouchEvent -- not recommended), you can't do what you want.  MotionEvent dispatching is based around finding a target via the first recipient who returns true and then dispatching all following events to that target.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess what I need to know then is how to have a touch listener on a custom view that doesn't disallow the implementing class to have its own fully functional touch listener, but you've definitely answered the question in the title.

Comment: Why you don't simply put your "event monitor code" in the dispatchTouchEvent?

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
  //Monitor touch events here instead of inside the onTouchEvent,  then dispatch them normally
  return super.dispatchTouchEvent();
}

Answer (score 1):

return `true` on the `onTouch()` event.
This mean we are still waiting on some new Actions from this event so other events like `OnClick()` is disabled.

On action `ACTION_UP` you need to return `false` at least to not get issues with other events after it.