# Receive callbacks for touch events without disrupting normal flow

Tags: android, android-view, touch-event

I want my callback to be fired on every touch event for a particular view. I've found similar question: [View.onTouchEvent only registers ACTION_DOWN event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391748/view-ontouchevent-only-registers-action-down-event) by there is no direct answer.

If `true` is returned from `onTouch()` then further events belonging to the same touch (eg. `ACTION_MOVE`) are reported, but flow is disrupted and normal event processing does not happen (eg. View is not entering in pressed state).

If `false` or `super.onTouchEvent` is returned then only `ACTION_DOWN` is reported but not other actions and normal processing happens correctly (eg. View is entering in pressed state). Unfortunately other callbacks like `onInterceptTouchEvent()` aren't called as well.

I want to be both notified on all touch events (`ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE` and so on) and not disrupt normal processing (eg. View should enter correct state when touched). How to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend your particular `View` and overwrite `dispatchTouchEvent` like this

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    handleTouch(ev);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

And implement handleTouch to do whatever you want to do without disrupting the normal flow.

Comment: Just return `super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)` instead of true.

Comment: Except when your actual view didn't consume the ACTION_DOWN you also wouldn't get the ACTION_MOVE. If you want to do something with that you need to call `super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);` and return `true`

Comment: Effects are respectively the same as in my question. If I return `true` I receive further `ACTION_MOVES` but normal processing does not happen and vice versa if there is `return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);` then normal processing happens but I don't receive further actions.